# Why can't Typescript use keyof type of a generic in an assignment and generalizes it to string?

Tags: typescript, generics, keyof

I came across a curious Typescript assignment error and I'm trying to understand more about why it doesn't work. For reference I'm using TS `3.9.2`.

The code:

```
function test<U extends object>(a: U, k: keyof U) {
    const x: Partial<U> = { [k]: a[k] };
    // ...
}
```

The error:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: U[keyof U]; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<U>'.
```

The problem is only present when I'm using generics, for example if instead of `U` I use a concrete interface, then it works as expected.

I'm assuming that the type system in not able to infer correctly the keys of `U` and use them during the assignment, why is that? I inspect the type of `k` inside `{ [k]: a[k] }` it correctly returns `keyof U` so I don't fully understand why the type system can't use that information to check if the assignment is legal and generalize `k` to `string`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the only reason, that it's not working, that typescript doesn't fully understand your intentions, because you create a new Object and there is no information about it.

In this case better to tell compiler, that now you have Partial of original Object like that

```
function test<U>(a: U, k: keyof U) {
    const x: Partial<U> = { [k]: a[k] } as Partial<U>;

    return x;
}
```

and it will work

Comment: I agree, that will work as expected, but I wanted to understand a little better why it works with a concrete interface and doesn't work with generics.